# How to develop Meteor JS app with multiple output interfaces?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

1. **Interface 1 (e.g. Tab):** will deal with orders, mainly placing them
2. **Interface 2 (e.g. Preparation and Packaging, using a simple monitor, no input required):** what they need to prepare and pack shown in the monitor
3. **Interface 3 (e.g. Manager, PC/web):** Looks into inventory and supply.

***Question is how to have these multiple interfaces for multiple roles with multiple tasks under each on a single Meteor JS app?***

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into using the alanning:roles package: https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles

That will allow you to allow/disallow access to actions/interfaces by roles you define and give to users.